# How to get the value of the Promise after it is resolved in node REPL

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I have some code like this which I am trying in Node REPL:

```
result = lib.utils.kv["@0.1.16"]
    .get({ key: "t2" });
```

Now I want to access the value in the string after it is resolved. When I try to print result, I first get
`Promise { <pending> }`

Then after sometime, I get

```
Promise {
        `'{"locations":{"CH":5000013960,"AE":5000013961,"AF":5000013961}}'`
}
```

I want to get the output without the Promise prefix, and also ideally without that backtick.

I have tried to use an alternative syntax, but not sure whether this is the only way and whether this is even the right way?

```
(async () => {
  result = await lib.utils.kv["@0.1.16"]
    .get({ key: "t2" });
  console.log(result);
})();
```

Comment: @Bravo, I have node 16.3 - but I still get the error if I try it without IIFE

Comment: Oh, sorry ... REPL ... ignore me, I'm stupid